Manjaro no longer shuts down
Since a few days ago, shutting down Manjaro just leads to a black screen with the mouse cursor.
There is usually another bootable drive connected to the system, but this wasn't a problem before. Consequently, I believe this is the result of a recent system update, but I can't be sure.
Following advice from a forum thread, I tried editing /etc/default/grub. Locating the following line:
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet udev.log_priority=3"

I first added acpi=force, then, seeing no change, apm=power_off:
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet udev.log_priority=3 acpi=force apm=power_off"

I did run a sudo update-grub command after each attempt, before shutting down.
I've read that ACPI arguments do nothing if the system has no /proc/acpi/ directory, which I do have. I haven't been able to determine whether the system has or uses APM.
What is preventing Manjaro from shutting down properly?

Have you looked at the logs?

I haven't... Not sure where the log files are, but I've just tried running "last reboot | less" in the terminal and it's mostly crashes for the last four days. Apparently two successful shutdowns too, which I have no memory of.

I found a solution that worked for me, so I'm referencing it here. Though I'm gonna leave my other "answer" up, just so that the comments and the train of thought makes sense.
It's not my own solution and I actually just found it in this thread on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/ManjaroLinux/comments/1fvxt1n/manjaro_does_not_shut_down/
by a user named rick_bisqit .
In System Settings / System / Session under "Restoring Session" check the box to "Start with an Empty Session" (maybe someone with an english system language can check if I translated that correctly...).
Then I restarted my system once more via command line and now I had the first clean shutdown (by mouse / graphic interface) in weeks. I hope that also solves your issue!

And there's the solution! Still a workaround, but it fixes the problem, with minimal drawbacks. Personally, I close everything before shutdown, so I didn't even know Manjaro was saving open windows and programs. Thanks for the help; I still hope the core issue is solved at some point, but for now it's no longer something I need to think about.

I also didn't know that, so same. But now it's here, so hopefully others with the same problem have a higher chance of running into this solution.

I have the same problem. I know this is not truly an answer. Im new here and maybe you can point me to the correct way to add information, but since I couldnt comment, this is the way I choose for now. Im gonna post an interim solution at the bottom though (which I guess is part of the information...kind of).
I also tried the mentioned fix of the author first but to no avail.
Anyways the last correct shutdown I had was on the 27.09.2024 on kernel version 6.1.106-1. The first crash appeared on the 01.10.2024, which was also the last shutdown on this kernel version. I cant remember for sure, but I guess that was the session I updated my kernel version to 6.1.111-1. The update to 6.1.112-1 on 11.10.2024 didnt solve the issue but funnily enough my reboot log thinks now that the last session is still running in addition to the current one. Since the bug appeared I have also noticed that the shutdown screen changed. Before when clicking on shutdown in the start menu, there was an overscreen showing all the options including reboot etc. Now the "new" overscreen only shows shutdown and cancel.
I have noticed, that shutting down the system via shutdown now still works as usual, which is right now my go-to option. For an easy double click solution you can just put a small bash file like "shutdown.sh" with the following content on your desktop:
#!/bin/bash

shutdown now


Not bad! I hadn't even thought about terminal commands or shell scripts. It isn't exactly what I expected, but it's a convenient workaround assuming, perhaps generously, that a future OS update solves the issue permanently. At least worth an upvote.

Thanks! I mostly wanted to try and give more information and attention to the issue (also since I have it myself) and while I like Linux and Manjaro, I am not too well versed. Since the problem doesn't appear very widely and wasn't fixed in the last kernel update though I fear we are a little on our own. Since it doesn't appear to be a common problem (then I'd have guessed its in how graphic shutdown is called) I guess something that is checked in the graphic (mouse click) shutdown creates this point of failiure. This portion does not appear to be called in "shutdown now" though.

There's probably some system repair utility that could fix it, or at least diagnose a clear cause. Barring an official fix though, I've been looking more into Ubuntu as a replacement anyway, since it has the most third-party software and hardware support, and a massive user community.

Fair enough. I just wish there was a solution, since I'm not looking to change distros any time soon. But it appears like there are not a lot of people with this problem around, so I guess its gonna be shutdown now for a while ^^
